# Where are the control points for a non-parametric b-spline?

Tags: spline

There are many wonderful illustrations of parametric curves with b-splines and control points, but I mostly use splines for uni-variate functions.  So I have a vector of control *values*, but not really *points*--at least not ones I can easily plot.

If we take the three examples in the definition section of the wikipedia article on B-Splines:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline

[image]

How could I determine the control point positions in each example in order to visualize them on the graphs?

Comment: I would be happy to receive comments on how to improve this question.  I'm puzzled that it gets no reaction at all...